# WIKIDATA/SPARQL: How to get the used language when using SERVICE wikibase:label with [AUTO_LANGUAGE] parameter

Tags: sparql, wikidata

About everything in the title : When I use
`SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }` I may get some results with the detected [AUTO_LANGUAGE] and others in 'en'.
Is it possible to get the used language for each of the lines of the result ?

Comment: https://w.wiki/ZSo or https://w.wiki/ZSr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. `LANG(?var)` does that:

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel  (LANG(?itemLabel) as ?langLabel)
    WHERE {
        ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q146.
        SERVICE wikibase:label { 
            bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "de,fr,en".   
        }
    }
```